# Inconsistent speed improvements with parallel execution in R?

Tags: r, performance, foreach, parallel-processing, doparallel

I'm trying some basic things with parallel programming in R. The results have been very inconsistent.

My first technique was to use the parSapply() function from the "parallel" library. The results are consistent. As I add more cores to the parallel process, speed improves notably:

```
library(parallel)

# Initiate test list
testlist <- 2:10000000

# Initiate test function
testfunction <- function(x) {
  c(x, x^2, x^3)
}

# Calculate the number of cores
no_cores <- detectCores()

# Initiate cluster
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
clusterExport(cl, "testlist")

# Execute things
system.time(parSapply(cl, testlist, testfunction))

# Close cluster
stopCluster(cl)
```

However, my second method uses the foreach() function from the "foreach" package. Its results are **not consistent**. When I use 2 cores instead of 1, speed improves. However, when I use 3 or 4 cores, there is **no improvement**. Why is this happening?

```
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

# Initiate test list
testlist <- 2:100000

# Initiate test function
testfunction <- function(x) {
  c(x, x^2, x^3)
}

# Initiate separate parallel function
parallelfunction <- function(x) {
  foreach(x = testlist, .combine = c, .export = "testfunction") %dopar% {
    testfunction(x)
  }
}

# Calculate the number of cores
no_cores <- detectCores() - 3

# Create an implicit cluster
registerDoParallel(no_cores)

# Do things
system.time(parallelfunction())

gc()

# Stop implicit cluster
stopImplicitCluster()
```

I test by changing the "no_cores" value. (i.e. `no_cores <- detectCores() - x`). The list size didn't make a difference with this.

Comment: I guess the answer is the same, as for the difference between `for` loops and `apply` functions. Apply function is vectorised, so it calls R functions just a few times, and bulk calculations are done internally with high speed. When using `for` or `foreach` with a long `i` parameter, R functions get called very often which results in low speed. In case with parallel computing, the system wastes extra time and resources to decide which core should calculate what and to provide memory to every core. Basically, you should always optimize your code first, and then think about parallelization

Comment: @MaksimGayduk "Apply function is vectorised, so it calls R functions just a few times, and bulk calculations are done internally with high speed." That's not correct. You don't have less calls to the function with `apply` than with a `for` loop.